# Trying to find a count of items from a two level deep association, any ideas?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-key-relationship

I am working on an application where I need to find the count of submitted items by users that have been referred by a user.

For Example -

*User1 has referred 3 people (User2, User3, User4) and each of those users has submitted 5 articles.*

I am trying to find a way to get the count of submitted items in User1's tree (should be 15 in this case).

My user model looks like the following (simplified)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Code for user referrals
  belongs_to :referrer, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :referrals, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "referrer_id"
  has_many :items
end
```

I can find out the count for each user easily (User.items.size), but I am having trouble finding a solution to get the referral counts as one sum.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
user = User.find(1)
total_items_size = user.referrals.map(&:items).flatten.size
```

Comment: That's quite a novel way of doing it! I will keep that in mine for some other relationships that wont be as large as the users/referrals one!

If I could add some rep for you I would...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use select_value to manually run the SQL query:

```
def referred_items_count
  select_value("select count(*) as referred_items 
  from items inner join users on users.id = items.user_id 
  where users.referrer_id = #{self.id};", "referred_items")
end
```

The benefit is that it is a lot more scalable than using Ruby to count.

Comment: This was something I found on another post but wanted to keep raw SQL out but it looks like this is the best and most efficient way or doing it.

Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Get all items of User with id of 1

```
total = 0
Users.find(1).referrals.each do |refer|
   total += refer.items.size
end
```

Comment: I had tried this but for a large number of referred users it will become quite an overhead. I will also looking at caching the count on the user model but wanted to stay away from that.

Thanks!